# Assigning function with arguments to a variable in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I created a Buttons Class using this code

http://nathandemick.com/programming/tutorial/2014/09/23/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift.html

But the **action** variable doesn't have arguments
If I change init and the action to be

```
 var action: (id: Int) -> Void
```

After that I can't execute the function in touchesEnded method

```
func test(){
    println("test");
}

func testTwo(id: Int){
    println("testTwo");
}


var action: () -> Void;
action = test
action() // prints test

var actionTwo: (id: Int) -> Void;
actionTwo = testTwo

// This work
actionTwo(id: 9); // prints testTwo

// But I want this to work
actionTwo();
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to work without arguments if you yourself defined the function to require an `Int` argument?

Comment: I don't expect it to work, i just want to be able to pass an argument

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your function a definition that makes the integer argument optional.

```
func testTwo(id: Int? = nil) {
   print("something")
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work, in the tutorial the function have to be execute in **touchesEnded**

Comment: In the init you have  action = buttonAction, but in **touchesEnded** I can't execute it without passing the id, so i have to send action(id: 5), id: 5 ..

Answer (score 0):

If you define your function with a variable number of arguments, such as

```
    func testTwo(args:Int...) {
        println("testTwo")

        // enumerate over arguments
        for arg in args {
            println (arg)
        }
    }
```

and then define/assign your variable appropriately with

```
    var actionTwo: (args:Int...) -> Void
    actionTwo = testTwo
```

you can invoke the function with/without arguments by

```
    // This works
    actionTwo(args:9)

    // and this also works
    actionTwo()

    // and, BTW, this works as well
    actionTwo(args:1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```